# Print required lines from 3 files in Unix

Tags: unix

There are 3 files in a directory. How can i print first file 1st line, Second file 3rd line and Third file 4th line using UNIX command ?

I tried with cat filename.txt| sed -n 1p but it is applicable for only one file. How can I view all the three files at a time ??

Comment: Look at `find` and `xargs`.

Comment: you don't need to use `cat` (see [UUOC award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)).. `sed -n '1p' filename.txt` will do just fine... I think you are after [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) but if you just need output on terminal, simply issue all three commands separated by `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk. at the beginning of each file `f` is increased to follow which file we're dealing with then we just team that up with the required record number of each file (`FNR`):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {f++} f==1&&FNR==1 || f==2&&FNR==3 || f==3&&FNR==4' 1 2 3 
11
23
34
```

Record of the first file, the others are similar:

```
$ cat 1
11
12
13
14
```